# How would i add a event when i hit the obstacle it restarts

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a small game, and I'm trying to implement a "game over" function when I hit the obstacle. But every time I add all of the code to implement that feature it destroys everything. I would gladly appreciate if someone could help me. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Here is the entire code (only the js part):

```js
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacle;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 225, 225);
    myObstacle = new component(40, 40, "green", 300, 120);
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 1000;
        this.canvas.height = 890;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },    
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.moveAngle = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore();    
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
        this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
    }

}

function updateGameArea() {

    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.moveAngle = 0;
    myGamePiece.speed = 0;
    myObstacle.update();
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.moveAngle = -2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.moveAngle = 2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speed= 2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speed= -2; }
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

startGame();
```

Comment: You're looking for polygon v polygon collision. Here's one article I found on google: https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/collision-detection-circles-rectangles-and-polygons/

Comment: Seems like one of the w3schools.com games. If you kept following their tutorials, you would find information on hit detection. See if you can implement a function from here https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_obstacles.asp

Comment: I am using w3schools. I've followed every step, but every time i add the hit detection part, the entire canvas disappears

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing this:
You have missing semicolons on line 14 and 17
Let's see...

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is called 2D Collision detection. If you're going to use squares, it's rather simple. Basically, compare the two squares with the following:

```
if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
   rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
   rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
   rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y) {
    // collision detected!
}
```

Taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

This code only works with squares without any rotations. For rotation, you would have then have to break out the trigonometry functions of sin/cos/tan based on the angle of rotation.

There are multiple solutions to 2D collision. One method, based on having personally used this for geofencing, is to take every point of Object 1 and compare it against every side of Object 2. If there are an odd number of sides in one direction of a point (for example, to the right) then that makes it's inside the object. You would iterate this for every point and `return true` if any return odd. You should then repeat process inverse process with Object 2 points.

This is called a Point-in-Polygon approach:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

This works with polygon shapes, but once you use curves, it gets harder. But, generally, gaming uses "hitboxes" because of the simplistic nature.

Edit: To note, this Point-in-Polygon works if the hitboxes are the same size, but if you can overlap two rectangles against each other, then you would have to compare the intersection points of each side of Object1 with sides in Object2.